# Microsoft Security Essentials crashes when I try to install it

Tags: windows-vista, ms-security-essentials

Microsoft Security Essentials crashes when I try to install it.  32-bit Windows Vista Home Premium.  Latest version, just downloaded a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved on my own.

Turns out you can't let the installer lose focus or it crashes.